# onClick in a loop with Ajax does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops

I have this function below. It's a simple loop that look over a list of projects. For each project, it makes a NeDB query (does not matter here, just consider that it works as an Ajax function) that retrieve the tasks corresponding to the project and then display the tasks and an Edit button.

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log('Work');
}

$.each(projects, function( index, project ) {
  // tasks.find takes 100ms, it's like an Ajax request
  tasks.find({}, function (err, tasklist) {
    $('#my-list').append('<li>Edit</li>');       
  });
});
```

I would like that when I click on Edit, it runs myFunction().

So usually, I would have used on click like this :

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log('Work');
}

$.each(projects, function( index, project ) {
  // tasks.find takes 100ms, it's like an Ajax request
  tasks.find({}, function (err, tasklist) {
    $('#my-list').append('<li>Edit</li>');
    $('#my-list li').on('click', function(){
      myFunction();
    }
  });
});
```

The problem is that the on click function is in a loop, so it creates the function for each iteration of the loop, so it print 'Work' as many times as there are projects.

I also tried this

```
$('#my-list').append('<li onClick="myFunction()">Edit</li>');
```

But it does not recognize my function

What is the solution ?

Comment: Why not just pull your `on.click` functionality out of the loop?

Comment: @Pytth because it does not apply the event on the li element because the li element is created after that tasks.find ends. So if I put on.click out of the loop, it runs on.click before the li elements are there.

Comment: that makes complete sense. I also wrote an answer where you can just add the `click` event to the parent container so it only get's called once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should only listen to `click` event of 1 `<li>` element

```
function myFunction() {
  console.log('Work');
}

$.each(projects, function( index, project ) {
  // tasks.find takes 100ms, it's like an Ajax request
  tasks.find({}, function (err, tasklist) {
    var $newLi = $('<li>Edit</li>');
    $newLi.appendTo('#my-list');
    $newLi.on('click', function(){
      myFunction();
    }
  });
});
```

Hope that this can help :)

Comment: Thanks :) I made a variant var length = projects.length; and in the loop : if (index === (length - 1)) { myFunction() }

Answer (score 1):

Change your `on.click` functionality to:

```
$("#my-list).on("click", function(e) {
   // You can access the specific element child clicked
   // by using $(e.target);
   myFunction();
})
```

Comment: No Prob! This is also a great solution to have in your toolbox for when you might have 1000 items that would otherwise all require `click` listeners be added to them.